# while loop to find largest number less than

Tags: python-3.x

I want my program to get the largest number that is less than 12,000 when cubed but instead it goes to one number higher.

```
count = 0
cubed = 1
while cubed < 12000:
  count += 1
  cubed = count ** 3
print("The largest integer <12000 is", count)
```

Comment: Try: `print("The largest integer <12000 is", count - 1)`

Comment: Is there a way to make the program find it without editing the count in the answer?

Comment: Your program tries to find the largest number whose **cube is less than 12,000.**  Your text says you want the largest number less than 12,000.  You should clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop will only stop when `cubed >= 12000`.

If you want to make it stop before that, you will have to check whether `(count+1)**3 < 12000`, and only then do `count += 1`.

```
count = 0

while (count+1)**3 < 12000:
  count += 1

print("The largest integer <12000 is", count)
```

PS: simpler method is to take cube-root of 12000 and truncate to integer.

Comment: Thanks. its an assignment for school so obviously the simple method won't be the answer

Comment: @savannah lol. If you ever write code for your own projects/open-source use the simpler method, regardless of what school assignments may demand.